# dependent dropdown in form edit laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Hello everyone i need help.
I make dynamic dependent dropdown in Laravel 8, when create data it's work, but when i will edit data, dependent dropdown not selected in view edit.

My code like this,

**view.blade**

```
<label class="font-label">Provinsi</label>
<select name="prov_ktp" id="prov_ktp" class="form-control forms-input">
    <option value="">Pilih Provinsi</option>
    @foreach ($provinsi as $key => $prov)
        <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $prov }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>

<label class="font-label">Kota/Kabupaten</label>
<select name="kab_ktp" id="kab_ktp" class="form-control forms-input">
    <option value="">Pilih Kota/Kabupaten</option>
</select>

<script>
    $('#prov_ktp').change(function() {
        var provinsiID = $(this).val();
        if (provinsiID) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "{{ url('get-kabupaten') }}?id_provinsi=" + provinsiID,
                success: function(res) {
                    if (res) {
                        $('#kab_ktp').empty();
                        $('#kab_ktp').append('<option value="">Pilih Kota/Kabupaten</option>');
                        $.each(res, function(key, value) {
                            $('#kab_ktp').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>');
                        });
                    } else {
                        $('#kab_ktp').empty();
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('#kab_ktp').empty();
            $('#kec_ktp').empty();
        }
    });
</script>
```

**myController**

```
// function display provinsi
public function showDalamNegeri() {
    $provinsi   =   Provinsi::pluck('nama_provinsi', 'id_provinsi');

    return view('data_pribadi.dalam_negeri', compact('provinsi'));
}

// function display kabupaten
public function getKabupaten(Request $request) {
    $kabupaten  =   Kabupaten::where('id_provinsi', $request->id_provinsi)->pluck('nama_kabupaten', 'id_kabupaten');

    return response()->json($kabupaten);
}
```

**Route for display Kabupaten**

```
Route::get('get-kabupaten', [DataPribadiController::class, 'getKabupaten'])->name('getKabupaten');
```

Thanks.

Comment: which select is not working? `prov_ktp` or `kab_ktp`?

Comment: also try to log `res` inside `success` to check what it contains